# When should I return a reference from a function

Tags: php, function, variables, reference, pass-by-reference

I'm reading the PHP documentation about [Returning values](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php). Honestly I cannot understand how *Example #3* works exactly. Or when should I use such a template.

```
<?php
function &returns_reference()
{
    return $someref;
}

$newref =& returns_reference();
```

I've executed it [online](https://3v4l.org/HMdJG), but it returns nothing. Anyway, can you please tell me when should I use it in practice? Or at least give me a more clear example?

Comment: that is a bare-bone example shown in the doc, for more explanation you can check this page http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php#language.references.return and to learn more about references you can check "Reference Explained" page http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/)

```
<?php
    $someref = 3;
    function &returns_reference(&$someref)
    {
        return $someref;
    }

    $var = &returns_reference($someref);
    $var = 5;
    echo $someref;
```

Comment: Curiouser And Curiouser !

Comment: @stack will you check it.